# Получение данных из iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

Есть iframe, который я формирую, в нем input'ы `[type='radio']`. Мне нужно узнать какой radiobutton выбран

```html
<iframe src="pictures.php?fon=first" width="500" height="300" id="first">
  Ваш браузер не поддерживает плавающие фреймы!
</iframe>
```

```php
<?php

$i=1;
$files = scandir('/images/'.$_GET['fon']);

foreach (array_slice($files,2) as $file) {
?>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <label for="<?php echo $file; ?>"><img src="/images/<?php echo $_GET['fon'].'/'.$file; ?>" width="100"/></label>
        <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $file; ?>" name="<?php echo $_GET['fon'].'[]'; ?>" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" >
    </div>
    <?php if($i%4==0):?><br><?php endif; ?>
<?
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Можно в родительское окно передать данные/вызвать функцию через `window.parent`. Например, `window.location.href=...` перезагрузит текущий фрейм, `window.parent.location.href=...` перезагрузит родительский фрейм/окно. Т.е. вам, при выборе чекбокса надо будет сообщать родительскому окну о выборе.

Comment: а можно поподробнее? я новичок, поэтому фактически ничего не понял, в каком файле и что именно написать?

Comment: Автор, если бы вы сделали рабочий пример на jsfiddle, вам бы прямо в нем код и поправили. А так никто этого делать не станет.

Answer (score 1):

Ваши радиобаттоны должен быть такими:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="window.parent.myButtonSelected(1);"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="window.parent.myButtonSelected(2);"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="window.parent.myButtonSelected(3);"/>
```

А в родительском окне, которое содержит `iframe`, соответственно, нужна такая функция:

```
function myButtonSelected(num) {
   alert("Выбрана кнопка номер "+num)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

у инфрейма свой контекст. туда даже яваскриптом не залезть.

сделан специально. чтобы например в формы логинов социалок не лазили.

Comment: Получается что получить элементы или значения из iframe не возможно ?